# How to embed MathML in an ontology and reference parts of it

Tags: rdf, ontology, owl, mathml

I'm fairly new to MathML, so I apologize if this is a silly question. I'd like to embed MathML 3.0 into an ontology (RDF/OWL etc). But I'd like the variables in the equation to refer to entities in the ontology.

For example, for the equation (**a** + **b**) where **a** is represented by **exampleontology#a** and **b** by **exampleontology#b**, would I do something like:

<apply>
<csymbol cd="arith1">plus</csymbol>

<ci id='exampleontology#a'>a</ci>

<ci id='exampleontology#b'>b</ci>

</apply>

I'm not sure what is the most appropriate way to embed these references.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer on semanticweb.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20140525064410/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/871/mathematical-expressions-in-rdf) to a related question about encoding mathematical expressions in RDF might be helpful for the desired goal.

It introduces an OpenMath-based vocabulary for mathematical objects as well as for cross-referencing between mathematical expressions and RDF resources and properties (see also [OpenMath content dictionary for RDF](http://www.openmath.org/cd/contrib/cd/rdf.xhtml)). Since OpenMath is also fully compatible with Strict Content MathML it is easy to convert between both representations.

Answer (score 1):

MathML and OWL are traditionally both serialised into XML using their own independent particular tags (example: `<owl:Class rdf:about="exampleontology#A"/>`). So it is not possible like that, you have to find a work around.

What you could do is to create an ontology and then link some MathML code via an OWL annotation property (e.g. `mathml`). You could then retrieve the MathML code later by accessing the value of the annotation property.

For instance if you save the following block of code as .owl file and open it with Protege 4 you should be able to understand the pattern:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
<!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
<!ENTITY demo "http://www.example.org/demo.owl#" >
<!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
<!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
<!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
]>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.example.org/demo.owl#"
 xml:base="http://www.example.org/demo.owl"
 xmlns:demo="http://www.example.org/demo.owl#"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.example.org/demo.owl"/>

<owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="&demo;mathml"/>

<owl:Class rdf:about="&demo;a">
    <mathml rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">&lt;ci&gt;a&lt;/ci&gt;</mathml>
</owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<apply> <csymbol cd="arith1">plus</csymbol>
<ci id='exampleontology#a'>a</ci>
<ci id='exampleontology#b'>b</ci>
</apply>
```

`#` isn't a valid character in an XML ID, I think the most natural way here is to equate your ontologies with an OpenMath Content Dictionary Then you could go

```
<apply> <csymbol cd="arith1">plus</csymbol>
<csymbol cd='exampleontology'>a</csymbol>
<csymbol cd='exampleontology>b</csymbol>
</apply>
```

the content of the csymbol is taken as the name of the symbol in the content dictionary.

You could but don't have to use the OpenMath Content Dictionary syntax to describe the systems or you could just directly manage the ontology as OWL.

There are some old files starting some mappings between rdf/owl and openmath views of the world for example

http://www.openmath.org/ontology/README

The openmath  list at http://www.openmath.org/lists/index.html is probably the best place for getting in contact with people interested in OpenMath/MathML and RDF/OWL

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To clarify, if I used 'exampleontology:a' or another ID that is a valid XML ID, would this be okay? Or is the content dictionary approach still preferred?

Comment: the id attribute (as in html and most vocabularies) is supposed to be unique in the document and identifies _that_ element, it is an anchor for inward links not an outward reference.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to define a new datatype for MathML literals. Let say http://www.w3c.org/datatypes/mathMLLiteral.  (ideally it should be defined by W3C)

In Turtle format, this would look like this:

```
@prefix math:<http://example.org/ont/math#>

:APlusB a math:Addition
   math:serialization """<apply> <csymbol cd="arith1">plus</csymbol>
                         <ci id='exampleontology#a'>a</ci>
        <ci id='exampleontology#b'>b</ci>

        </apply> """^^<http://www.w3c.org/datatypes/mathMLLiteral> .
```

A similar encoding pattern is used in [GeoSPARQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoSPARQL) standard, where geometries are encoded in WKT or GML. Geosparql introduces two different datatypes for each: http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#wktLiteral and <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#gmlLiteral